# Prevent page refresh when button click without using UpdatePanel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

How i can prevent page refresh when button click without using UpdatePanel in asp.net ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i need to create tab control that contains slidershow , is there another method to prevent page refresh since updatepanel not working with tab control perfectly  ?

Answer (score 0):

use `OnClientClick="return false;`

```
<asp:button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" text="Button" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want to use an UpdatePanel, but this might work with your tabs, though I'm not completely sure. From what I've seen, you can create a "dummy" UpdatePanel that just holds your AsyncPostBackTriggers, then match them to your control handlers. I just ran across something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlAsync" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName ="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave1" EventName ="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnBackgroundTasks" EventName ="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnReSubmit" EventName ="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnSubmit" EventName ="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It is matched up with button controls, but they are not in an UpdatePanel themselves. When the Click handler is called in the code behind, the subroutine gets called, but the page doesn't refresh. I realize that this isn't really how the triggers are intended to be used, but it seems to work for my situation. Maybe it will work for yours.